# How to validate json unnamed array in karate

Tags: karate

**I am trying to validate the below response which is an array without array name.**

```
[
    {
        "soldTo": "0000100139",
        "productId": "88175838",
        "catalogNumber": "130C-3/4X30FT",
        "manufacturerName": "3M CO. - ELECTRICAL MARKETS DIV.",
        "quantity": "000001",
        "lastPurchaseDate": "Jun 13, 2018 12:00:00 AM",
        "description": "30-feet x 3/4-inch black Scotch&#174 linerless rubber splicing tape.",
        "imageUrl": "https://static.graybar.com/supplierimages/3m_new/130C-1-12X30FT-th.png"
    },
    {
        "soldTo": "0000100139",
        "productId": "25438652",
        "catalogNumber": "312-POUCH",
        "manufacturerName": "3M CO. - ELECTRICAL MARKETS DIV.",
        "quantity": "000011",
        "lastPurchaseDate": "Jul 27, 2018 12:00:00 AM",
        "description": "Yellow Scotchlok&#8482 electrical spring connector in a pouch for 22 to 8 AWG wire.",
        "imageUrl": "https://static.graybar.com/supplierimages/3m_new/312-BAG-th.png"
    },
    {
        "soldTo": "0000100139",
        "productId": "88175944",
        "catalogNumber": "33+SUPER-3/4X66FT",
        "manufacturerName": "3M CO. - ELECTRICAL MARKETS DIV.",
        "quantity": "000001",
        "lastPurchaseDate": "Jun 13, 2018 12:00:00 AM",
        "description": "66-feet x 3/4-inch black Scotch&#174 Super 33+&#8482 vinyl electrical tape.",
        "imageUrl": "https://static.graybar.com/supplierimages/3M_New/MMM_33Super34x66FT-th.png"
    }
]
```

**when I trying to use below match each script getting an error.**

```
And match each response.soldTo == '#string'
    And match each response.productId == '#string'
    And match each response.catalogNumber == '#string'
    And match each response.manufacturerName == '#string'
    And match each response.quantity == '#string'
    And match each response.lastPurchaseDate == '#string'
    And match each response.description == '#string'
    And match each response.imageUrl == '#string
```

'

**Error:** com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: Expected to find an object with property ['soldTo'] in path $ but found 'net.minidev.json.JSONArray'. This is not a json object according to the JsonProvider: 'com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JsonSmartJsonProvider'.
    at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.matchNamed(StepDefs.java:540)
    at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.matchEquals(StepDefs.java:526)
    at ✽.And match each response.soldTo == "0000100139"(previously-order-items/previously-order-items.feature:24)

Comment: Using below script getting another error:

And match each response == 
'   """
    {
     soldTo: '#notnull', 
     productId: '#string', 
     catalogNumber: '#string', 
     manufacturerName: '#string', 
     quantity: '#string', 
     lastPurchaseDate: '#string'
     description: '#string'
     imageUrl: '#string'
    }
    """
'
**Error:** 
com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: net.minidev.json.parser.ParseException: Unexpected token d at position 166.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a mistake in your JsonPath. Please read the docs and examples more carefully.

```
* match each response[*].soldTo == '#string'
* match each response[*] contains { productId: '#string', catalogNumber: '#string' }
```

Comment: Using * match each response[*] contains { productId: '#string', catalogNumber: '#string' } getting the same com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: net.minidev.json.parser.ParseException: Unexpected token d at position 166.
 at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.matchNamed(StepDefs.java:540)
 at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.matchContains(StepDefs.java:532)
 at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.matchContainsDocString(StepDefs.java:519)
 at ✽.* match each response[*] contains(previously-order-items/previously-order-items.feature:25)

Comment: @ManojKumarKotturi ok I give up. it works for me. all the best ! https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thank you! * match each response[*].soldTo == '#string' this worked for me